CSP reporting frame-src request for pwm-image.trendmicro.com (trend micro password manager) - should I allow?
In our report-to logging for our CSP I am seeing frame-src request from Trend Micro password manager. Has anyone run across this before?
frame-src   pwm-image.trendmicro.com


It could be a browser extension or third party resource. I wouldn't add that URL to the CSP unless you understand the reason why it is required.
If you allow frame-src   pwm-image.trendmicro.com means you're allowing iframes in your website with the src attribute pointing to pwm-image.trendmicro.com.
